# Is "join a group of people to do [something]" grammaticaly correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I've used the "join a group of people to do [something]" structure in the following sentence:

> I was invited to *join a team of three other engineers to develop a knowledge-based system for neuromuscular disorders*.

Is the sentence grammatically correct? What I mean is that I was invited to join a team of three other engineers and our task was to develop a knowledge-based system for neuromuscular disorders.

Comment: Perfectly correct. This is using "to" in the sense "in order to".

Comment: You probably don't need "other", since it is implied in context (you are joining them).

Comment: I would keep the 'other'. While technically user3169 is correct, people are often not that explicit with their words. 

A 'team of three' may not have three actual people but three positions for people. He could be the third person, making it total three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is grammatically correct and reads fine.

Was there a particular part that you were worried about?

Comment: I was worried about the "join a group of people to do [something]" structure.